# picked items on radiobuttons, checkboxes & comboboxes will display in one message box visualC#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

How can I display user's selected item on radiobuttons, comboboxes and checkboxes on one message box when cmdShow is clicked? For example the user picked male, Z-City, Running, Intermediate. The message box will show all of them.There are 4 group box (g1- Radiobuttons(2), g2- combobox(1), g3- checkboxes(6), g4-radiobuttons(4)) So far this is my code and it's not working.

```
    private void cmdShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sex, activity, city, level;
        foreach (Control S in Frame1.Controls)
        {
            if (S is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton Se = (RadioButton)S;
                if (Se.Checked == true)
                {
                    sex = Se.Text;
                }
            }

        }

        foreach (Control S in Frame2.Controls)
        {
            if (S is CheckBox)
            {
                RadioButton act = (RadioButton)S;
                if (act.Checked == true)
                {
                    activity = act.Text;
                }
            }

        }
        foreach (Control S in Frame4.Controls)
        {
            if (S is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton Lvl = (RadioButton)S;
                if (Lvl.Checked == true)
                {
                    level = Lvl.Text;
                }
            }
           

        }

        string a = sex + activity + level;

        MessageBox.Show(a);





        cmdNew.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: `if (S is CheckBox) RadioButton act = (RadioButton)S;`? When you have CheckBoxes, more than one can be checked, so why just get the last one checked? -- You should probably explore the functionality of DataBindings, binding your Controls to a class object (you can bind the `Text` property, if that's what you need).

Comment: Note that you can  write, e.g., `if (S is RadioButton rb && rb.Checked) { }`

Answer (score 0):

First, give each control meaningful names. Next, the logic for `foreach (Control S in Frame2.Controls)` does not make sense, check for a CheckBox but cast to RadioButton.

Consider the following extension methods which are designed to use for more than one task and when placed into a class project can be used for other task.

Or copy code from the following [link](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/team-controls/blob/master/ControlHelpers/ControlExtensions.cs) on GitHub.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static RadioButton RadioButtonChecked(this Control control, bool Checked = true) =>
        control.Descendants<RadioButton>().ToList()
            .FirstOrDefault((radioButton) => radioButton.Checked == Checked);

    public static IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this Control control) where T : class
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T thisControl)
            {
                yield return (T)thisControl;
            }

            if (child.HasChildren)
            {
                foreach (T descendant in Descendants<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then used as followed. You would then modify the code for when no selection is made if that is a requirement as shown in the left image below.

```
private void GetSelectionsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    var selectedGender = GenderGroupBox.RadioButtonChecked()?.Text ?? "Unknown";
    var selectedLevel = LevelGroupBox.RadioButtonChecked()?.Text ?? "Unknown";

    builder.AppendLine($"Gender: {selectedGender}");
    builder.AppendLine($"Level: {selectedLevel}");

    MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());

}
```

For other controls, like ComboBox, that is easy enough, check if there is a selection than act accordingly. And CheckBoxes ,a simple lambda or linq statement can provide what is needed.

[image]